# Could not write JSON: Cannot override _serializer with Spring-data-rest and spring-hateoas

Tags: java, jackson, spring-data-rest, spring-data-neo4j, spring-hateoas

I am making a Spring Data Rest application but would like to return a custom representation of my object data so I have created a DTO and a Controller to convert my entity to the DTO and return a HAL formatted response.
However invoking the custom controller returns a 500 and this message:

```
2018-03-01 16:22:02.478  WARN 14044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Cannot override _serializer: had a `org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalLinkListSerializer`, trying to set to `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$NestedEntitySerializer`; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot override _serializer: had a `org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalLinkListSerializer`, trying to set to `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$NestedEntitySerializer` (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.Resources["_embedded"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap["personDtoes"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {

@RequestMapping("/peopleDto")
public HttpEntity<?> personDto() {

    Iterable<PersonDto> personDtos = Collections.singleton(new PersonDto("Testy McTest"));
    for (PersonDto personDto : personDtos) {
        personDto.add(linkTo(methodOn(PersonController.class).personDto(1)).withSelfRel());
        personDto.add(linkTo(methodOn(PersonController.class).personDto(1)).withRel("person"));
    }
    Resources<PersonDto> resources = new Resources<>(personDtos);
    resources.add(linkTo(methodOn(PersonController.class).personDto()).withSelfRel());

    return new ResponseEntity<>(resources, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

DTO:

```
public class PersonDto extends ResourceSupport {

    private final String name;

    @JsonCreator
    public PersonDto(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I was not able to find anything online about this specific error and I have tried to strip away any unrelated complexity but it seems the problem is specifically related to the serialization of my dto as a Resorce.
Is spring-data-rest and spring-hateoas not playing well together?
Any tips to how to get around this?

Comment: Maybe my demo [project](https://github.com/Cepr0/spring-data-rest-dto) will be helpful...

Comment: Yes! Thank you that was helpful. I'm still a bit unsure what caused the error but aligning my code to your example worked